# Ngbootstrap: how to position dropdown under search input

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

I'm following [this documentation](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/dropdown/examples) cause I would like to create a
Gmail like 'search bar' where beside the input there's a dropdown button that opens a dropdown with filter options.

Unfortunately in the docs the examples don't cover the **input + dropdown** button scenario.

I started with this:

```
<!-- Search bar-->
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <input type="text" class="form-control">
  <div class="input-group-append" ngbDropdown role="group" aria-label="Button group with nested dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-success" ngbDropdownToggle></button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" ngbDropdownMenu>
      <button class="dropdown-item">One</button>
      <button class="dropdown-item">Two</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Everything is shown correctly, but the dropdown is not. It is opened under its parent (the button), while I'd like to have it for the whole length of the input. Pretty sure it could be solved with some CSS rule.

Comment: From the documentation you could attach the dropdown menu to the input group and trigger the open/close with a the appended button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/dropdown/examples#manual) under `Manual Triggers`,  you could attach the dropdown menu to the input group and trigger the open/close with the appended button on click event.

```
<!-- Search bar-->
<div class="container">
  <div class="input-group mb-3" #myDrop="ngbDropdown" ngbDropdown>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" >
    <div class="input-group-append"  role="group" >
    <button (click)="$event.stopPropagation(); myDrop.open();" class="btn btn-outline-success" >Hi</button>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" ngbDropdownMenu>
     <button class="dropdown-item">One</button>
    <button class="dropdown-item">Two</button>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```